# Pegar URL Formulário

Tags: php, formulário

tudo bem?

Possuo um formulário dentro de uma determinada pasta, por exemplo, dominio.com/formulario/, porém, vou usar este formulário dentro de uma outra página, por exemplo, dominio.com/sobre onde eu precisaria que quando o usuário preenchesse este formulário chegasse para mim o link dominio.com/sobre  que ele usou para acessar o formulário e não onde ele é processado.

Tentei usar: $pagina_referencia = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; mas ele sempre me retorna onde é processado..

Existe alguma forma?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual a forma que vc está usando para colocar um formulário de uma página em outra? Seria bom inserir essas informações no corpo da pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode resolver isso criando um campo do tipo hidden contendo como value o endereço da página, usando o window.location do javascript desse jeito:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="hidden" name="endereco" id="endereco">
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#endereco").val(window.location);
</script>
```

Note que se você inpecionar o elemento verá que no valor do campo estará o link da página, e no seu código PHP você saberá de onde veio este formulário.

Comment: Desta forma também está pegando somente onde o formulário é processado.. eu estou fazendo o seguinte: tenho o formulário hospedado em dominioc.com.br/formulario - coloquei este formulário em lightbox no dominiob.com.br/sobre, eu precisaria que a informação do endereço fosse: dominiob.com.br/sobre mas ele sempre me retorna dominioc.com.br/formulario que é onde o formulário é hospedado

Comment: Impossivel! o `window.location()` retorna o endereço atual da página, ou seja, se o formulário estiver em dominioa.com retorna dominioa.com, se vc copiar ele e colar no dominioc.com ele retorna um dominioc.com, a menos que esteja usando um `iframe` que eu não sei qual seria o resultado.

Comment: estou usando um iframe..